# unable to fetch base64 value from image file in angular

Tags: angular

i am trying to upload an image from input type=file using this html->

```
 <input id="inputFileToLoad" [(ngModel)]="flowerdetails.flImage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  type="file" (change)="fileloader()" />
            <div id="imgTest"></div>
```

what this does is call a method name called fileloader in my component's .ts file after choosing a file from local storage using this->

```
 fileloader(){
    this.data = encodeImageFileAsURL();


    console.log("data",this.data);
  }
```

this encodeImageFileAsURL is created in another .js file in project like this->

```
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
       
        var base64 = btoa(fileLoadedEvent.target.result);

        console.log("bas64 is "+base64);
        return base64;


        

      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);

 
    }

  }
```

now if i try to c.log the base64 value in js file i get some value but if i do this in ts file i get `data: undefined` in console. and i dont know whats going on. I want base64 value from the file so that i can send it to an api which is connected to a db where flowerdetails.flImage has datatype varbinary. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent {
  data = undefined;
  flowerdetails: any = {};

  async fileloader() {
    this.data = await this.encodeImageFileAsURL();

    console.log('data', this.data);
  }

  encodeImageFileAsURL() {
    let filesSelected = (<HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById('inputFileToLoad')
    )).files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      let fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      let fileReader = new FileReader();

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
          let srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result as string; // <--- data: base64

          let newImage = document.createElement('img');
          newImage.src = srcData;

          document.getElementById('imgTest').innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;

          let base64 = btoa(srcData);

          console.log('bas64 is ' + base64);
          return resolve(base64);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
      });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('NO file selected');
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8lhe5k?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: did u try it. it still says 'data undefined'.

Comment: @mordor619, ok, for example, resolve from the function what's needed ... ( fixed code above as a sample)

Comment: ok the method works but turns out the btoa isnt converting image to correct hex value. can u help with that

Comment: ... what to You mean " turns out the btoa isnt converting image to correct hex value" ..? - `btoa` base64-encodes your string (what hex do You expect?) ... if not what you want - well, .. use `toDataURL` or use fileReader: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL , or  somthing like that ...

Comment: i want to convert the image file to a hex value. how to do that in angular? i want to send that value to api